There's something rotten in the tag of regex, episode M + 1 of N: Unwarranted deletion of a question
This is about the, to me unwarranted, deletion of the following post: RegEx to selectively insert newlines (line breaks) works on regex101.com, but not in PowerShell (screenshot, courtesy of Anon Coward)
Preface:

Anecdotally, it seems that the incident at hand is part of a larger pattern, hence the title.
Disclosure: I am one of two answerers who responded to the deleted post. Independently, the deletion should be judged solely on its own (lack of) merits.
Additionally, in my opinion, deleting a post with answers that have garnered 7 net up-votes (without any down-votes), is questionable in and of itself. Whether such a post should be closed is a separate matter. In the case at hand, I believe that neither closure nor deletion is warranted.


As for the question at hand:

It contrasts unsuccessful PowerShell efforts with successful, seemingly equivalent, regex101.com efforts, asking for an explanation of this discrepancy.

Because regex101.com is an indispensable resource when it comes to answering regex questions across many languages/regex engines, not only is the specific question valid, it is also of general interest to PowerShell users who wish to avail themselves of this resource.

Despite all that, the question not only (inexplicably to me) received 3 down-votes (offset by an up-vote from me), but, even worse, was eventually deleted.

Note that prior to its deletion, the question was closed as a duplicate of Regex how to replace <'string'> with a new line but keep the 'string', which has no relationship with regex101.com whatsoever. To me, that closure was mistaken, and therefore later reverted.




Actionable items:

I suggest undeleting the post, as it may benefit future readers.

Those who down-voted and/or voted for deletion are invited to share their rationale for doing so.



Obviously it's a vandal deletion by pretty the same "voting-circle" that cast their unjustified delete-votes since years. And yes, it's most annoying if you spend your time adding valuable content to valid and interesting questions just to find it deleted, not "just" closed a couple of weeks or month later. The Regex tag sadly has been site of conflict for years and still is a dangerous place of ⚡ high-voltage.

Indeed, @bobblebubble. The linked post is now undeleted, and the duplicate closure has been undone.

For me, this should be undeleted.
When I read the question, I found everything I was looking for in a valid question:

Well on-topic for Stack Overflow
Example input and example output, with an explanation of what they want
Explanation what they tried, by giving a code example
Focused on one problem: the line is truncated

I read all the comments and I see that they report that there are other problems. But in fact, a lot of other questions have this type of issue too. There are other problems which make the code harder to understand, slower, etc. But solving a secondary issue doesn't make the code work, and it should not be a reason to close or delete.
Here, the given code could be better, and mklement's answer explains how. It seems to have been helpful for at least 6 people. The help center explains that a question with a good answer should not be deleted. There is also a second answer that proposes another way to fix the same problem. So it's also a good answer, which can also help about "the OP is talking about 2 differents regex but gave only one" (note: IMO the OP would like to make the first regex works before making the second one).
To conclude, I can understand that this post is not one of the best and can be rejected by some people, but it seems helpful for Stack Overflow, and in this case, should not be deleted.

I am the author of that question.
I was fairly new to PowerShell and regular expressions, I was still trying to figure out how to best participate in SO as well. Reading the help articles, I tried to do my best in explaining myself and what I was trying to do, hence why I was using RegEx101 in the first place.
Reading some of the answers/comments here, I understand my shortcomings and have taken them on board.
The answer I got really did help me and a few others (as indicated by its votes), it was clear and concise, as well as directly providing a solution for the question I had, it also explained critical parts I was confused on, \n vs `n etc.
I was not even aware of this answer being deleted, I don't fully understand the rules and culture that governs the deletion of posts on this site, I believed my question was meeting the rules of the site but since it was deleted, I am not so sure anymore.
Moving forward, I will have to take extra precautions when posting on SO and maybe even start archiving my posts, as I have misjudged the long term availability of the material I post on here to be more reliable than what I post on the equivalent Reddit page.

It has since been undeleted. Having taken the points made here into consideration, I'd welcome you to think about specifically what you want the question to be about, and try to edit it to meet standards. At any rate, the golden rule here is that content is not personalized, and content curation is not personal.

IMO, this should not be undeleted
There are multiple things wrong here with how the question is posed.

OP seems to have it in mind that two different regexes should be used to match before and after the bulleted list (i.e.: the last line before the list and the first line of it, and then the last line of the list and first line after it). But the question shows the same regex (with different replacement patterns) both times. This was presumably a copy-and-paste error in asking the question. (Doug Maurer's answer takes a completely different approach, by matching the list and putting a newline both before and after.)

The question asks about why "the line itself gets truncated" (apparently intended to mean that it's missing from the output). Then in a separate place, it tries to show the wrong output, but doesn't try to characterize what is wrong with it. This is inconsistent and unclear.

The question blatantly needs more focus because there are two unrelated things wrong in the example: the PowerShell syntax (for specifying the replacement), and the logic behind the replacement. The question is further de-focused by raising the (incorrect) suspicion that the problem relates to some difference in regex syntax (i.e. for the regex itself) between PowerShell and regex101.com. If this were intended purely as a how-to question, then it should have been asked as one, rather than as a debugging question. But then it is really more of a problem-solving question than a programming question.


There is also noise that should have been edited out, although this is not a reason to close or delete questions. But fixing the core issues with the question entails asking a fundamentally different question (actually, two new questions, one of which - the one you answered - isn't really about regex.)
OP's main objection to the observed result - that the resulting output is missing lines after replacing the regex with the first capture group and then a newline, "even though" the capture group is just a newline - makes no sense. The line is missing because the capture group is just a newline: the entire match is replaced, using a replacement that contains the capture group (a newline) and a newline - i.e., two newlines. This would have inclined me to close the question as caused by a typo or possibly look for a duplicate. The duplicate that was proposed doesn't appear to be relevant, sure; but at least based on the title, it's an understandable attempt. The problem is how to replace some matched text with the same text plus a newline (Doug Maurer's answer incidentally showed how to do that).
If the OP sincerely thought that "replacing" matches of '\n-\s.*(\n)[^-]' should replace only the captured newline with the replacement pattern, then that was certainly not clear from how the question was phrased. (Of course, that also suggests yet another approach to solving the problem, using look-ahead and look-behind assertions.) For example, if that's the underlying mental model, then I can't understand what OP thought should happen if there are multiple explicit capture groups, or why OP didn't try using \n\n as a replacement instead.

As an aside, it is not necessary to know anything about regex101.com to answer the question, understand the problem, or discuss the Q&A on Meta. That website is completely irrelevant here, because the question is not about how to use the site for the purpose of determining regexes (the only thing that would make it on topic for Stack Overflow). For that matter, it's not even about the actual regex (but instead about the logic for using the regex, as well as PowerShell syntax).
"It worked on regex101" doesn't actually matter. First off, using the regex that OP apparently workshopped on regex101, for text replacement in the described manner (as opposed to, say, merely matching or searching for the regex) clearly doesn't work. But "it worked in some other environment" is generally noise - because if "it" actually does work in that environment (such that you know that the environment is the problem in the actual code), then knowing about the working environment does not help understand the problem.
Aside from that, the question is not about regex101.com, and there was never any attempt to tag or describe the question as such. Thus, it is clearly not relevant that any proposed duplicate "has no relationship with regex101.com whatsoever".
